# Azure Data Factory Pipeline is failing

Tags: azure-data-factory

[image]Operation on target jb_Rental_Object_Occupancy_State failed: {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: com.microsoft.dataflow.Issues: DF-FN-056 - toString accepts locale only for date/timestamp and time zone only for timestamp type - EXE-0001,Dataflow cannot be analyzed as a graph,[418 473 564 737],\ntrROOccStaterefV162S23P290658926JoinSurrKey95JoinAddDerived derive(\n) ~> trROOccStaterefV162S23P290658926JoinSurrKey95JoinAddSelect\nDF-FN-056 - toString accepts locale only for date/timestamp and time zone only for timestamp type -

Not sure what is happening here.. below is the sample code.

case(((isNull(FROM) && !isNull("00000000")) || (!isNull(FROM) && isNull("00000000")) || FROM != "00000000") && ((isNull(length(trim(FROM))) && !isNull(0)) || (!isNull(length(trim(FROM))) && isNull(0)) || length(trim(FROM)) != 0),  case(!isNull(toDate(FROM, "yyyyMMdd")), toDate(FROM, "yyyyMMdd"), toDate(null())), toDate(null()))

Comment: Could you please provide what you have tried?

Comment: I tried with toString() and changed format of yyyyMMdd also didn't work. Do you have any remedy if so plz comment.

Comment: Could you please provide your pipeline images?

Comment: Added in above description.

Comment: @John, can you provide the values for the column `FROM`? and also the expected result if possible?